# How far apart are the rudder pedals on a Piper PA-28?

Tags: flight-controls, rudder, piper-pa-28

How far is the left rudder pedal from the right pedal on a Piper PA-28? I assume the left and right seats have equal pedal spacing, but if not, the left seat is what I would like to know.

Comment: Is "several inches" close enough?  What sort of accuracy or tolerance do you need?  *(these things aren't typically listed in the POH, so it's an oddly specific request you will probably need an owner or renter to actually measure...)*

Comment: Gosh I don't know off the top of my head, but I fly one and I'm going out for a bimble tomorrow, weather permitting, so I can measure if you need any sort of accuracy

Comment: @Jamiec just an approximation is fine; I'm building a set of pedals for my simulator.

Comment: Approximately how far apart your feet are if you are sitting with your legs out straight. ;)

Comment: What Chris said.  Most small GA airplanes have similar spacing.  Make it a comfortable fit for you, the actual measurement of a PA-28 really isn't important.  I'd almost be inclined to close the question based on the information not being useful to the general community.

Comment: @MichaelHall if you want to close it that's fine with me; I'm not concerned about it knowing that the precise separation won't matter.